# Parallelizing std::nth_element and std::partition

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, parallel-processing, opencl

I'm porting C++ code which uses `std::nth_element` and `std::partition` to OpenCL.

[`nth_element`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/nth_element/) is a [selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) which places the nth-smallest number in an array at the nth spot, and arranges the remaining elements so that all elements less than this number are before it in the array, and all elements greater than it are after it.  In effect, `nth_element` sorts the array into 3 buckets: the number itself, all the numbers less than it, and all the numbers greater than it.

Canonically, `nth_element` is implemented using a recursive partition: an element is chosen, the elements are partitioned based on whether they're less than this element.  Then, pick the bucket which contains the nth element of the array and recurse on that bucket.  The main difference between `nth_element` and a full quicksort is that quicksort recurses on both buckets, not just the one containing the nth element.

---

[`partition`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partition/) is a weaker version of `nth_element` which only sorts the array into 2 buckets: those for which a condition is true, and those for which it is false.  The site I linked to gives the implementation:

```
while (first!=last) {
    while (pred(*first)) {
        ++first;
        if (first==last) return first;
    }
    do {
        --last;
        if (first==last) return first;
    } while (!pred(*last));
    swap (*first,*last);
    ++first;
}
return first;
```

where pred is a function that evaluates whether an element should be in the first bucket.  Basically, this function iteratively finds the outermost pair of elements of the array which are in the wrong place, and swaps them, stopping when the pair of elements are the same element.

---

Here are my initial ideas on parallelizing `nth_element` and `partition`:

Partition could be implemented using atomic comparisons and swaps, but I'm not sure how to cover all the possible pairs of values which could be swapped.  There's no obvious way to divide the work among multiple threads, since partition requires comparing elements which may be either right next to each other or at opposite ends of the array.  I also don't see a way to avoid having thread B compare with an element which has already been swapped by thread A, which is inefficient.

nth_element seems even less parallelizable, since it is recursive: each partition depends upon the elements having been partially ordered by the previous partition.

Presumably, an efficient parallelization strategy will require a completely different approach than the typical serial code, for both functions.

---

Do efficient parallel implementations of `nth_element` and `partition` already exist?  If not, what is a good parallelization strategy?

Comment: nth_element is more iterative than recursive (unlike quicksort, which requires two recursive calls); paradoxically, that makes quicksort easier to make parallel once the initial (and largest) partition is done. Google search on "parallel partition" found this presentation: http://www.lsi.upc.edu/~lfrias/research/parpar/wea08.pdf amongst other interesting hits.

Comment: @rici Good point about iterative vs recursive.  However, since the iteration in `nth_element` depend completely on the results of previous iterations, it can be thought of as recursion, as well.  Also, thanks for the link!  There are some very good ideas in there.

Comment: partition could be achieved by dividing the range into two roughly equal portions using std::advance(). You then use 2 threads to partition each using the single-threaded version.
Afterward you need to call rotate on the two middle portions. This is like stable_partition dividied into two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuda THRUST has partition function implemented (http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/index.html#reordering).

The main idea should be following:
Using prefix sums to calculate position of element in the array and then rearrange the array.

Comment: This approach with prefix sums will work only for numbers, but not for arbitrary objects and `operator <`.