# SIMD Implementation of std::nth_element

Tags: c++, performance, sse, simd, stl-algorithm

I have an algorithm that runs on my dual-core, 3 GHz Intel processor in on average 250ms, and I am trying to optimize it. Currently, I have an `std::nth_element` call that is invoked around 6,000 times on `std::vector`s of between 150 and 300 elements, taking on average 50ms. I've spent some time optimizing the comparator I use, which currently looks up two `double`s from a vector and does a simple `<` comparison. The comparator takes a negligible fraction of the time to run `std::nth_element`. The comparator's copy-constructor is also simple.

Since this call is currently taking 20% of the time for my algorithm, and since the time is mostly spent in the code for `nth_element` that I did not write (i.e. not the comparator), I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way of optimizing `nth_element` using SIMD or any other approach? I've seen [some questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515772/parallelizing-stdnth-element-and-stdpartition) on parallelizing `std::nth_element` using OpenCL and multiple threads, but since the vectors are pretty short, I'm not sure how much benefit I would get from that approach, though I'm open to being told I'm wrong.

If there is an SSE approach, I can use any SSE instruction up to (the current, I think) SSE4.2.

Thanks!

Comment: can you post some code? what are you trying to optimize?

Comment: @BЈовић I can post _something_, but I'm not sure how useful it would be. I have several thousand lines of code, and I'm trying to optimize all of it. It's a vision algorithm. What would you like to see?

Comment: Yeah, we're going to need some more context here.  You've got a bunch of smallish vectors of doubles, and you're trying to sort them for some reason?  What's your ultimate goal?

Comment: Each vector contains a similarity score, and I'm going to iterate over the top 5% of the scores, and then continue on with the processing. I'm using `nth_element` to get a partition of the scores into the top 5% and the rest. I (obviously) don't care about the relative order in each group, only that the best scores are in the first slots of the vector. Is that enough context?

Comment: @anjruu: Some time back I had a similar problem (although with `float`s instead). I spent some time looking into SIMD-suitable `nth_element` algorithms and eventually just settled on doing a full sort instead. I used the "in-core" variety of the [AA-sort described in this paper](http://researcher.watson.ibm.com/researcher/view_person_subpage.php?id=3982). Fully sorting the vector and then just picking the index I wanted turned out to be significantly faster than using `std::nth_element()`.

Comment: @JasonR Great looking paper, thanks for the reference.

Comment: You need to be sure that the time is spent executing the code of nth_element, not accessing the memory which contains the elements themselves.  I don't know how big the elements are, but in some detailed performance work I've done, it's basically turned on that the the processor is effectively infinitely fast, and that touching memory is all that really costs time.

Comment: I wonder if the repeated calls to `nth_element` are somehow triggering a worst-case behavior on already-almost-sorted data for the partition algorithm.  As a sanity check, I'd definitely try sorting the whole vector and accessing elements.

Comment: wait, are you calling `nth_element` 6000 times on a 150-element vector, or once each on 6000 150-element vectors?

Comment: I loop over a set of features. In each loop, I generate a vector of scores, generally around 150 elements, and call `nth_element` on that vector of scores. The loop runs around 6000 times.

Comment: In addition to `nth_element` and the algorithm suggested in the accepted answer, you might want to performance test `std::partial_sort`, which can be very effective when you only need a very few elements at one end of the sorted sequence.  Additionally, implementations of `nth_element` can vary significantly among implementations.  It is possible that switching vendors could have a significant impact on your performance.

Comment: @JasonR Is there any chance that your source code for AA-sort is open source? It would really help me a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two thoughts:

1. Multithreading probably won't speed up processing for any single vector, but might help you as the number of vectors grows large.
2. Sorting is too powerful a tool for your problem: you're computing the entire order of the vector, but you don't care about anything but the top few.  You know for each vector how many elements make up the top 5%, so instead of sorting the whole thing you should make *one* pass through the array and find the `k` largest.  You can do this is `O(n)` time with `k` extra space, so it's probably a win overall.